# React native picker is not showing the dropdown menu

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I try to make a dropdown menu using picker in react, but the picker is not showing in my app. I tried to add some fixes that I found but no luck at all. I try to add width, flex, change the alignItem, non of this seems to work. I have to mention the fact that I try to load in my picker items from a JSON file.

Here is my picker code:

```
<Item picker>
          <Picker
            mode="dropdown"
            iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" color={"#007aff"} />}
            style={{ width: undefined }}
            selectedValue={country}
            placeholder="Select your country"
            placeholderStyle={{ color: "#007aff" }}
            placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
            onValueChange={(e) => setCountry(e)}
          >
            {countries.map((c) => {
              return <Picker.Item key={c.code} label={c.name} value={c.name} />;
            })}
          </Picker>
        </Item>
```

And here is my form container, declared globally in another file.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

var { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const FormContainer = (props) => {
    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{props.title}</Text>
            {props.children}
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 30,
        marginBottom: 400,
        width: width,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 30,
    }
})

export default FormContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around, apparently if I do not apply height and width both in same time, it will not work.

Here is the updated code.

```
<Item picker>
      <Picker
        mode="dropdown"
        iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" color={"#007aff"} />}
        style={{  height: 50, width: 150 }}
        selectedValue={country}
        placeholder="Select your country"
        placeholderStyle={{ color: "#007aff" }}
        placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
        onValueChange={(e) => setCountry(e)}
      >
        {countries.map((c) => {
          return <Picker.Item key={c.code} label={c.name} value={c.name} />;
        })}
      </Picker>
    </Item>
```